# How to pass @instance variable to my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up a new web application, and want to add personalized offers, if a user chose "ebay offers" for example. I only want to display the offers for ebay. How do I need to call the instance variables inside my view, to render the relevant offers?

In the past, I've tried `@services.service_type` or `@service.service_type` and nested variables for example `@services.user.service_type`, but nothing seems to work.

My dashboard/index.html.erb

```
<% if current_user.is_ebay && @services.service_type %>
...
<% end %>
```

My dashboards_controller

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
     @services = current_user.services
  end
 end
```

#### EDIT

My User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :services
end
```

My Service Model

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: can you show the relationship between table User and Service

Comment: And what is `service_type`? Is it a column or associated model?

Comment: @widjajayd I included the service.rb and user.rb file.

Comment: `service_type` is a column in the database.

Comment: @services.where(service_type: 'ebay') - you need AR query to find ebay services

Comment: @Vasilisa This doesn't seem to work. I get the following error: undefined method `service_type' for #<#<Class:0xa0680c0>:0xa1ebc90>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@services = current_user.services
# this will generate activerecord relation meaning couple of records
# you cannot access the column directly like @services.service_type

# to print the services you can do something like this 
<% if current_user.is_ebay %>
    <% @services.each do |service| %>
      <%= service.service_type %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```